# Different behavior of Calendar class in Java and Android

Tags: java, android, calendar

I was working on retrieving date of first week of the year and I found very strange behavior.

I tested the following code snippet both in Java console app and Android emulator and it produces different output.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Following output was produced

Android log cat : 2012/09/17 (incorrect)

Java console    : 2012/01/01 (correct)

And the strange thing is if I used following code both in Android and Java it produces same correct output. The only difference was I swapped the 2nd and 3rd line from the above code.

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
    cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Android log cat : 2012/01/01 (correct)

Java console    : 2012/01/01 (correct)

I am very curious to know regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is pretty interesting. Once I put cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) between WEEK_OF_YEAR line and DAY_OK_WEEK line, the output becomes correct. Can anyone guess the reason?

Comment: Good question. To clarify, when you say "Java", you are referring to Sun's (well, Oracle's) implementation?

Comment: @Cheezmeister Yes I am using Sun(Oracle) JDK

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that Calendar class internally has two data containers.

`protected long time`

`protected int[] fields`

So when you call `cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1)`, you change the values in `fields`, not `time` of the class.

In Java API

> protected abstract void computeFields()
>
> Converts the current millisecond time value time to calendar field values in fields[]. This allows you to **sync up** the calendar field values with a new time that is set for the calendar. The time is not recomputed first; to recompute the time, then the fields, call the complete() method.

I think in the first case of Android `computeFields()` is not called internally.

To check my theory, I tested the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(cal);
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
System.out.println(cal);
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
System.out.println(cal);
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

LogCat:

> java.util.GregorianCalendar[**time=1348010308802,areFieldsSet=true**,lenient=true,zone=org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.util.ZoneInfo["null",mRawOffset=0,mUseDst=false],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA==1,YEAR==2012,MONTH==8,**WEEK_OF_YEAR==38**,WEEK_OF_MONTH==4,DAY_OF_MONTH==18,DAY_OF_YEAR==262,**DAY_OF_WEEK==3**,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH==3,AM_PM==1,HOUR==11,HOUR_OF_DAY=23,MINUTE==18,SECOND==28,MILLISECOND==802,ZONE_OFFSET==0,DST_OFFSET==0]
>
> 2012.09.18
>
> java.util.GregorianCalendar[**time=?,areFieldsSet=false**,lenient=true,zone=org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.util.ZoneInfo["null",mRawOffset=0,mUseDst=false],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA==1,YEAR==2012,MONTH==8,**WEEK_OF_YEAR==1**,WEEK_OF_MONTH==4,DAY_OF_MONTH==18,DAY_OF_YEAR==262,**DAY_OF_WEEK==3**,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH==3,AM_PM==1,HOUR==11,HOUR_OF_DAY=23,MINUTE==18,SECOND==28,MILLISECOND==802,ZONE_OFFSET==0,DST_OFFSET==0]
>
> 2012.01.03
>
> java.util.GregorianCalendar[**time=?,areFieldsSet=false**,lenient=true,zone=org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.util.ZoneInfo["null",mRawOffset=0,mUseDst=false],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA==1,YEAR==2012,MONTH==8,**WEEK_OF_YEAR==1**,WEEK_OF_MONTH==4,DAY_OF_MONTH==18,DAY_OF_YEAR==262,**DAY_OF_WEEK==1**,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH==3,AM_PM==1,HOUR==11,HOUR_OF_DAY=23,MINUTE==18,SECOND==28,MILLISECOND==802,ZONE_OFFSET==0,DST_OFFSET==0]
>
> 2012.09.16

As we can see above, values in the fields are changed, but internal time is denoted as `?`, telling that `time` is not synced with `fields`.

You got unsynced `time` using `getTime()` method and printed it out.

I think Calendar in Android is designed to delay the sync until it is really needed.

**ADDED**

I found the following in Java API:

> Calendar fields can be changed using three methods: set(), add(), and roll().
>
> set(f, value) changes field f to value. In addition, it sets an internal member variable to indicate that field f has been changed. **Although field f is changed immediately, the calendar's milliseconds is not recomputed until the next call to get(), getTime(), or getTimeInMillis() is made**. Thus, multiple calls to set() do not trigger multiple, unnecessary computations. As a result of changing a field using set(), other fields may also change, depending on the field, the field value, and the calendar system. In addition, **get(f) will not necessarily return value after the fields have been recomputed. The specifics are determined by the concrete calendar class.**

**ADDED**

To check whether **"The specifics are determined by the concrete calendar class"** is true, I checked actual codes of Dalvik and JDK 6.

### Set method in Dalvik's Calendar

from https://www.codeaurora.org/git/projects/qrd-gb-dsds-7225/repository/revisions/cc99b832a941dc8cbb86f1607d04eb87935ddbfd/entry/android/dalvik/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/util/Calendar.java

```
public void set(int field, int value) {
    fields[field] = value;
    isSet[field] = true;
    areFieldsSet = isTimeSet = false;
    if (field > MONTH && field < AM_PM) {
        lastDateFieldSet = field;
    }
    if (field == HOUR || field == HOUR_OF_DAY) {
        lastTimeFieldSet = field;
    }
    if (field == AM_PM) {
        lastTimeFieldSet = HOUR;
    }
}
```

### Set method in JDK 6's Calendar

```
public void set(int field, int value) {
    if (isLenient() && areFieldsSet && !areAllFieldsSet) {
        computeFields();
    }
    internalSet(field, value);
    isTimeSet = false;
    areFieldsSet = false;
    isSet[field] = true;
    stamp[field] = nextStamp++;
    if (nextStamp == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        adjustStamp();
    }
}
```

Specific implementations are pretty different.
To figure out the exact reason of your problem, you should look at both implementations in detail.

Comment: So can we say this as a bug in Android SDK?

Comment: @VishalVyas It's not a bug. From the excerpt of JAVA API in my answer: get(f) will not necessarily return value after the fields have been recomputed. `The specifics are determined by the concrete calendar class.`

Comment: @VishalVyas I checked the actual codes of Dalvik Calendar and JDK 6's Calendar and found that they have different implementations. I added more about this to my answer.

Comment: calInst.getTimeInMillis() worked for me when i had this issue